# Independent And Dependent Events(3 coins)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, intersection-theory

https://www.teachoo.com/4152/768/Example-12---Three-coins-are-tossed--three-heads-or-three-tails-/category/Examples/

Can someone give me an intuitive explanation of why E,G and F,G are dependent other than the calculations ?

Tossing 3 coins seems pretty independent to me.

Comment: The result *of the first coin* may be independent of the result *of the second coin* and such... but just because the scenario involves coins does not mean that more complicated events are dependent or independent of one another...

Comment: Of course each individual coin toss is independent of the others, but events derived from the tosses need not be independent.  As a simple example, if $A$ is the event "all the tosses are Heads" and $B$ is the event "all the tosses are Tails", then $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, so clearly dependent.

Comment: If you typed out the question, it might be more obvious: getting at least two heads reduces the probability of getting at most two heads, as you cannot get zero heads or one head

Comment: @Henry ..can you please elaborate? i feel like i am getting you..i am an high schooler just started with the basics of probability..

Comment: @lulu how are they related ?

Comment: @ JMoravitz how is that ?

Comment: I don't understand.  It is impossible to get both $HHH$ and $TTT$ out of three tosses, right?  So...knowing that you got $HHH$ tells you that you did not get $TTT$, and conversely.  That is a very strong dependence.  Computationally, sticking with my notation, $P(A\cap B)=0$ while $P(A)\times P(B)=\frac 1{64}$

Comment: Another example... if I flip a hundred fair coins in a row blindfolded and I ask "how likely is it given the information I have do I think that the first coin landed on heads?" you would be able to go back and say "Oh, that's just $\frac{1}{2}$" pretty easily, right?  Now... if I flip a hundred fair coins in a row blindfolded and you tell me "Oh, wow... 99 of those flips were heads"... Given that information how likely would I think it is that the first coin flipped was heads?  Not $\frac{1}{2}$ anymore...  That is to say with $A=\{\text{outcomes where first coin was heads}\}$ and...

Comment: $B = \{\text{outcomes where there were 99 heads}\}$ we would have $\frac{1}{2}=\Pr(A)\neq \Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{99}{100}$... That is to say... knowing that there were lots of heads, we are more inclined to believe the first coin was heads as well.  If our knowledge of one event having occurred influences our ability to predict whether another event has occurred or not, that is getting right to the heart of what we mean when we say two events are dependent.  Of course, it can be difficult to tell in some circumstances and so you really do need to formally check the calculations.